# OP-AMP Flip Flop start up predictability

Tags: operational-amplifier, flipflop

A customer had asked for a circuit design which I felt would be fun to implement using a couple of OP amps. (Its always fun to see if you can do something with op amps instead of a small MCU ). Anyway my circuit worked fine, but of course the customer then requested "just one" additional function, and it warranted an S/R flip flop. So, wanting to stay with the original design philosophy, I found the Op-Amp based SR flip flop circuit below. I implemented it and again everything worked fine. The circuit needs a "high" on either the SET or RESET inputs to toggle its state and conveniently (for me anyway), the circuit always powers up in the reset state. I've tried this with an LF353 I had handy, as well as a spare op amp in a TL084 in the customer's circuit, at a variety of voltages. For me this works out well, but I'm usually paranoid about start up "maybe" states. I suppose I could add a little RC network to the reset input (to force a little pulse on start-up). But if there is a good reason why its likely to be unnecessary, it saves me a couple of parts. :-) Can anyone see a good reason why this circuit reliably powers up reset?

[image]

Comment: Looks like the circuit diagram flip-flopped; it's inputs and outputs are on the wrong sides.

Comment: After a "long" [tm] time relative to any time constants a "powered off" capacitor will always start uncharged. This can be used to provide a startup "seed". An RC combination that is "weak"wrt set/reset or latch signals can be used so it will not affect subsequent operation.|| You can make an RS latch using two CMOS Schmitt inverters in series with a resistor from input to output plus 2 diodes for inputs. That gives 4 spare gates for other functions.

Comment: Why just not use a discrete flip flop IC? They cost 0.15$ on digikey and are more reliable, and higher speed. I guess it's fun for pedagogic purposes...

Comment: @lucas92. I had a quad op amp in the design with an unused gate when the person commissioning the circuit requested a function best handled by a latch. Space was already tight, and this proved a fairly painless addition.

Answer (score 2):

Sure can. It's the 10k to V+. As the circuit powers up, assuming the set and reset lines are held at the same value, the - input to the op amp will reliably be held higher than the + input. During the early stages of the power-up cycle, while V+ and V- are low, the output transistors in the op amp output stage are not able to produce much current. As a result, the output is not able to override the pullup resistor before the output state is established, and the reset state is established.

And your paranoia is justified. If you cannot guarantee the condition of the set and reset inputs during power-up, you cannot guarantee that they will not override the pullup resistor. So a POR (power on reset) pulse or level is ALWAYS a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. Duh! How did I miss that! Much appreciated sanity check. In fact, to force it to power up in the SET condition, I had to put a whopping 1uF from +V to the Set input, which doubly proves what you've well explained. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This does not answer the original question exactly but demonstrates a means by which the startup-reset state can be assured and shows another low cost and effective "Heath Robinson" means of achieving the desired aim. I have built many circuits using this approach with excellent results.

---

As an option to using an op-amp you could consider the use of  2 x Schmitt trigger input inverters (74C14 etc) as an RS latch.  Schmitt trigger input inverters are an immensely flexible and powerful building block for small tasks such as this.

A 3rd inverter can be used as an optional reset with a startup delay.
With care the reset function could be implemented with an RC arrangement without the 3rd inverter.

Below: IC1 + IC2 form a no inverting buffer with Schmitt triggered input.
R1 feeds buffer output to input forming a self driving latch.
D1. D2 provide Reset & Set signals which must be able to override the feedback latching signal via R1.

IC3 is an optional reset circuit.
C1 is discharged at startup so IC3 input is HIGH on power-up so IC3 output is low and provides a reset signal to IC1.  The R2 C1 time constant governs the length of reset signal.

R3 ensures that the reset signal level provided by IC3 dominates the startup conditions regardless of the state of the set or reset inputs.

The three "spare gates" are available for other uses - oscillators, delays or Diode-Resistor-Inverter logic gates.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWejqF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate that. In truth though the premise was that I already had an extra OP Amp in the package (a TL084) from my initial design. So even though there are other means to the end, the most eloquent thing (at least to me) is to use what's already available. Otherwise, an OP amp would not be my first choice for a FF. :-)\

Answer (score 1):

Without any inputs applied, the 10k pull down on the non inverting input will cause the opamp to always power up with the output low but, on a different opamp there could be reasons for suspecting a different result especially on an opamp that requires a minimum power supply voltage of several volts.

My reason is because if the output is closer to the positive rail whilst the power rails are below the value guaranteed for operation, there could be enough output voltage to forward bias the feedback diodes making the non inverting input higher than the inverting input when the rails finally get to the minimum level required by the chip.

I note that you have two diodes in series and presumably one diode isn't sufficient to guarantee the output being low at power up. Else why use two diodes?

Comment: Two diodes in the feedback path insures that the voltage on the + input is lower than the voltage of the reset pulse on the - input after it passes through its diode.

Comment: Right... I don't think it could have two stable states if not for that extra diode drop.